# SQL Average Price

Tags: sql, inner-join, average, aggregate-functions

I need a SQL query that will display the manufacture's name and average price. Thanks

Table 1 Products

```
+----+---------+-------+--------------+
| ID | Product | Price | Manufacturer |
+----+---------+-------+--------------+
|  1 | Game1   |   100 |            1 |
|  2 | Game2   |    50 |            2 |
|  3 | Game4   |    70 |            1 |
+----+---------+-------+--------------+
```

Table 2 Manufacturer

```
+----+-----------+
| Id |   Name    |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | Sony      |
|  2 | Microsoft |
+----+-----------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just join and aggregate:

```
select m.name, avg(p.price) avg_price
from manufacturer m
inner join products p on p.manufacturer = m.id
group by m.id, m.name
```